# How to read/access one line at a time from a .txt file in python?

Tags: python, file, gdal, txt

I have a .txt file that contains a list of counties, written one line at a time. Here is a sample image:

[image]

I would then like to call each line from this file in order to access a different .shp file which has names of the sort:

"001-almeda.shp", for example.

Thus, I would need to be stripping the 001-almeda first line of my .txt file to make this work. I am trying to use the .readlines() method but I keep getting a NoneType return error, so I don't believe that this is working. My code thus far is as follows:

```
with open('/Users/deas/Documents/Python/precinct-master/full-list.txt') as county_file:
    # NEED A WAY TO GRAB JUST ONE LINE AT A TIME WITHOUT A /n AT THE END
    for county in county_file.readlines():
        shp = '/Users/deas/Documents/Python/precinct-master/data/shapefiles/' + county + '.shp'

        source_ds = gdal.OpenEx(shp, gdal.OF_VECTOR | gdal.OF_UPDATE)
        source_ds.ExecuteSQL("ALTER TABLE "+county+" DROP COLUMN isHill")
```

Any help here is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide some details of NoneType error? At which line it is occurring?

Comment: You need to call `.strip()` on each line read from the file to get rid of the newline character.  Currently, you're generating filenames that contain a newline in the middle, which are almost certainly not going to refer to an actual file on your disk.